# Performance testing with Katalon Studio

Tags: jmeter, performance-testing, load-testing, katalon-studio

I am using Katalon Studio for Web and API testing. For performance testing, I use JMeter as Katalon Studio does not have support for performance tests.

I want to know if it is possible to do the following. Every test case is written in Katalon Studio for Web testing. I somehow must make so that, when test cases will run on Katalon Studio, it also should make performance/load testing. It is hard to rewrite everything in JMeter.

Is there any tool that looks at the running test cases and also makes performance tests? I mean, for example, one test case is for Login page, the user will log in into page and then it will log out. And for that, I want to get information about the time it took to log in and log out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do some kind of performance testing even with Katalon Studio itself, for example, by using `System.currentTimeMillis()` method like this:

```
long ts1 = System.currentTimeMillis()
WebUI.openBrowser("")
// test steps
WebUI.closeBrowser()
long ts2 = System.currentTimeMillis()
println("Test duration: "+(ts2-ts1)+ " miliseconds.")
```

Basically, you take the current time in any two moments during your test. That is ts1 and ts2. And you measure the difference between them.

So, login duration test might look something like this:

```
long ts1 = System.currentTimeMillis()
WebUI.setText('username-test-object', 'username')
WebUI.setText('password-test-object', 'password')
WebUI.click('login-button-test-object')
WebUI.waitForElementNotPresent('login-button-test-object')
long ts2 = System.currentTimeMillis()
println("Login duration: "+(ts2-ts1)+ " miliseconds.")
```

Comment: But I can't make that with multiple users yes ? For example, I want to test with 5+ users logging in the same time

Comment: No, this is just for measuring the time ("performance"). If you want multiple users, Katalon is not best suited for that, better use JMeter.

Comment: Now I've understood it, that answer will help me.